# Get offsetParent for text node with possibly display: contents on its parent

Tags: javascript, position

In the following example I can get `offsetParent` on a `div` and text inside of it, but with the `section`'s text I have a problem as `null` is returned. **Is there a way to get `offsetParent` preferably without traversing all parents in a loop?**

By the way [mdn article](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetParent) says nothing about `display: contents` affects `offsetParent` - it only mentions `display: none`.

```js
function logOffsetParent(node) {
  console.log(
    node.outerHTML || node.textContent,
    '    ',
    'offsetParent' in node
      ? node.offsetParent
      : node.parentElement?.offsetParent,
  )
}

logOffsetParent(document.querySelector('div'))
logOffsetParent(document.querySelector('div').firstChild)
logOffsetParent(document.querySelector('section'))
logOffsetParent(document.querySelector('section').firstChild)
```

```css
main {
  position: relative;
}

section {
  display: contents;
}
```

```html
<main><section>in section<div>in div</div></section></main>
```

PS: [Same question in Russian.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1561801/178988)